# Predicativo do Sujeito ou Adjunto Adverbial

Tags: verbos, sintaxe

Na frase: "Todos correram entusiasmados a maratona", **entusiasmados** seria um predicativo do sujeito ou um adjunto adverbial (no caso modificando o verbo correram)? [Neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mg8nF0mCv14&t=4s) (em 2:00) o professor afirma que é um predicativo pois atribui característica circunstancial ao sujeito, porém fiquei confuso pois pensava que os predicativos do sujeito eram sempre associados a um verbo de ligação. Alguém pode confirmar esta classificação?

Comment: Para mim, descreve como correram, então é um adverbo. "Eles ficaram entusiasmados." sería predicativo do sujeito.

Comment: Acredito que seja mesmo predicativo do sujeito, uma pessoa me chamou atenção do seguinte: "entusiasmados" está concordando com "Todos", e portanto não pode ser advérbio, o qual teria de ser invariável... nesse caso só posso concluir que essa premissa de que "o predicativo do sujeito vem sempre associado a um V.L." é falsa. :( 
Ahhh português...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que existem três tipos de predicado. O predicado verbal, o nominal e o verbo-nominal.
Quando temos um verbo de ação e um objeto, temos um predicado verbal:

```
    Todos correram a maratona
```

Um verbo de ligação sempre pede um predicado nominal, onde não há objeto, mas sim um predicativo do sujeito:

```
    Todos estavam entusiasmados
```

Na sua frase, temos um predicado verbo-nominal, onde temos um verbo de ação que pede um objeto, no caso, um objeto direto não preposicionado, e um predicativo do sujeito, que define o estado e concorda com o sujeito. Assim, entusiasmados só pode ser o predicativo do sujeito, já que um adjunto adverbial não estabelece concordância outras estruturas sintáticas.

Comment: luka, bem-vindo ao site. Concordo inteiramente. Poderias melhorar a resposta incluindo fontes. Por exemplo, encontrei [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/predicado-verbo-nominal/7259) e [esteoutro](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-predicado-verbo-nominal-e-o-predicativo-do-sujeito/26778), com a mesma análise e exemplos paralelos -- "ele correu assustado", "Maria saiu da igreja muito pálida". Se quiseres incluir estas referências e exemplos na tua resposta, estás à vontade.